# Index usage stats DMV indicates no index activity

Tags: sql-server, index

I'm trying to obtain information on indexes.  According to several websites, the below TSQL query should join information on indexes to the indexes table, returning indexes and related information.  The below query is simplified to the bare join, as I'm currently trying to return data and then from there, I will return what I need:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
     INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s ON i.object_id = s.object_id
```

This query returns nothing.  Yet, in several databases there are hundreds of tables that have at least one index, and according to various articles online, this query should return those indexes (because it's joining on the object ids).  Also, if I try to change the query to the below query, it returns nothing as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATABASENAME.sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN DATABASENAME.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s ON i.object_id = s.object_id
```

Why isn't this query returning data?

**Added**

If I run the below queries, I receive data from both of these `SELECT` queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

The problem (on the original query) is the `object_id` join.  However, I don't know why I have objects in one table that don't exist in another.

Final: Martin had the right answer originally - even though data was being returned from the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` table, it was on the `msdb` database, not the specific database I was seeking.  I ran queries on tables again, and found the database id in the table.  Unsure of why the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` table didn't retain data from previous queries on that database.

Comment: What db user is running the query, and what grants does that user have?

Comment: @MartinSmith If I use sa, running SQL Server express on my local machine with tables holding indexes, it also returns nothing.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, both tables return data individually.

Comment: No usage stats?

Comment: Ah re your edit. SQL Express auto closes databases by default so you probably lose it then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be that you don't have sufficient permissions to view the metadata.

Another is that `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` only reports on indexes that have been used at least once since the server was last restarted. [Also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx)

> whenever a database is detached or is shut down (for example, because
>   AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are
>   removed.

`AUTO_CLOSE` is the default for SQL Server Express.

You need to filter `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` by `database_id` to determine if it has metadata loaded for a particular database also the join should include `index_id`

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.indexes i
       LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats s
         ON i.object_id = s.object_id
            AND i.index_id = s.index_id
            AND s.database_id = DB_ID()
```